# function with undefined parameters

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm working with a calendar spreadsheet. This document uses background colors to designate different events. For example meetings are in blue, yardwork is in red.

I'm trying to create a (sum if bg color) method that looks at a given range in a google spreadsheet, counts the cells with a certain background color, assigns each block a weight (i.e. 30 minutes) and returns the amount of time spent in activities/week of that background color.

My essential problem is that my parameters are undefined (even though they're ranges) and range methods cannot be called on undefined object types.

Here's the code:

```
    //this function sums cells of a given color having assigned each cell a given value.
    //it inspects a range and compares each cell's background color to a given background color
    //returns given title and calculated sum
    function sumifcolor(theRangeToInspect, valueOfCellInRangeToInspect, colorAndTitleCell) {
        var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
        var color = colorAndTitleCell.getBackgroundColor(); //get color
        var title = colorAndTitleCell.getInputvalueOfCellInRangeToInspect(); //get title
        theRangeToInspect.activate();
        var firstRow = theRangeToInspect.getRow();
        var lastRow = theRangeToInspect.getLastRow();
        var firstCol = theRangeToInspect.getColumn();
        var lastColumn = theRangeToInspect.getLastColumn();
        var result;

        //for loops iterate through every cell in a row
        for (var yy=firstRow; xx<=lastRow; xx++) {
           for (var xx=firstCol; yy<=lastCol; yy++) {
                if (doc.getRange(xx,yy).getBackgroundColor() = color) {result += valueOfCellInRangeToInspect} 
           };
        };
      return title + ": " + result;    
    };
```

Comment: What would you expect the function to do when `theRangeToInspect` is undefined?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to use your function as a formula within a spreadsheet.

In which case, the range object will not be passed to the function but instead, the values in the range will be passed. Therefore,

```
theRangeToInspect.getRow();
```

will not work. theRangeToInspect will contain the contents of the range.

Comment: you assume correctly.

if a range is not passed into the function, is it sent as a 2d array? and does that array contain cell and text formatting, or just the cell value as a string/number?

Thanks Srik.

Comment: There is no formatting passed to the function, just the values, unfortunately. ANd yes, all these values as passed as a 2 array